# Mixing Php and Sql with Python

Tags: php, python, mysql, xampp

I'm making a sample page with php, and it's respective database with MySQL, In it, I ask for the user to insert the password and some other data(name, email...), I wan't to encrypt the password. I have the algorithm in a .Py file I made before, so I want to in some way insert it or make it work with the php so the password is revieved but not stored untill it is encrypted, and the so. Can I mix my files so it happen? I've heard of Python-Sql but I am not pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: You can have your PHP code call the python script using `exec()`.

Comment: P.S. For passwords, you can just use PHP's [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) function.

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html). If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: you'd have to pass the pw data from php->python, so technically it'll be exposed while it's moving between the two languages. why can't you implement the crypt stuff in php and save yourself having to create yet another secure communications channel?

Comment: The problem is that the Python code uses some python functions like `ascii()` and `repr()` so would it work?

Comment: ....srsly... it's python, they're ALL python commands...

Comment: The exec() command will run the python code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use the `exec` function or just put a shell command in these little backtick things ``

```
$password = `command to run python script here...`;
```

however, that's really overkill. Write it in PHP or use stuff that already exists like `md5()`

Comment: [NOT `md5()`!!!!!](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)

Comment: o pls, as long as your password isn't "password" md5 is fine for 75% of apps on the web.

Comment: Nope, it's not. Read the link and search the web for why md5 is not good for password hashing.

Comment: assuming 75% of the applications on the web only require a password to identify the user and not necessarily for security purposes.. i'm just saying, for like a game or something trivial like that..mi mean i'm not advocating it for everything but there's a time and a place for everything.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but `password_hash()` is easier and quicker than supplying your own salt and performing your own gyrations.

Comment: well, if we're still talking about trivial apps, that salt n stuff isn't necessary either. just md5 that shit and insert..